# kernel_task shutting down network when CPU not overheating

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, performance, power-management, temperature

[MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports), 2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB RAM, running Monterey 12.6.4]

`kernel_task` consumes inordinate CPU periodically--around 100+% according to command-line `top` utility.  At the same time all apps using the network lose their connection--e.g. disconnecting Zoom and any other streaming data for 30 seconds to several minutes.  As soon as `kernel_task` drops from the top CPU process, the network resumes.  Wi-Fi never drops, just the network traffic stops.  This is very disruptive.

I was told that `kernel_task` does this to cool the CPU because it is overheating.  I moved the power connector to one of the right side ports to run cooler (as suggested).  It made no difference.  Resetting the SMC seems to reduce the number of occurrences, but it eventually happens again in a week or two.

I wrote some scripts to log CPU temperature, fan speed, system load, and when `kernel_task` takes over. I'm getting CPU temperature and fan speed from running "`powermetrics --samplers smc`" as root.

I discovered several interesting items:

1. `kernel_task` almost never takes over (meaning 100%+ CPU use) when the CPU temperature is high.
2. `kernel_task` takes over at normal operating temperatures.
3. Fan speed doesn't change any differently with `kernel_task` taking over as if `kernel_task` doesn't do anything to fan speed.
4. `powermetrics` once showed a jump from 69C to 89C over a 5 second span while the fan speed increased by less than 1%.  Having a heat-sink on a CPU would make this unlikely.
5. Laptop is 2 years old but `kernel_task` was not recognized as a problem until the second year.  I don't recall network freezing at all during the first year.

From the above I'm thinking:

1. We've been lied to about what `kernel_task` actually does since behavior (consuming 100+% of the CPU) doesn't seem directly correlated with CPU temperature.
2. `kernel_task` doesn't directly address overheating.
3. `powermetrics` might be lying about temperatures, fan speeds, and when they occur.
4. SMC is an unreliable mess.
5. `kernel_task` unnecessarily throttles/shuts down network activity.

I don't really care about the temperature issues.  I want `kernel_task` to stop blocking my network connection at random times.  Is there a fix for any of this besides replacing the hardware?

Comment: I think there's a lot of inaccuracies in your assertions:  what do you consider a high temperature for the CPU?  What do you define as a  "normal" operating temperature?  Why must fan speed by directly correlated to kernel_task?  Why does a jump in temperature that's still well within the operating parameters of the CPU, for a short duration necessitate an instantaneous change in fan speed?  Why are you equating freezing of an image to be the result of kernel_task affecting networking?  There's lots here that appear very disconnected - can you shed some light on them?

Comment: 1.  I have thousands of data points for operating temperatures.  Normal is 65C to about 80C.  88C is running hot.  The max is 93C. I've never seen it go over 93C.    2.  kernel_task is said to take over and idle processes to bring the CPU temperature down.  It would make sense that it would turn up the fan speed, but apparently it does not.  3.  A jump of 20C degrees in 5 seconds I've never seen anywhere.  I've worked on clustered super computers where we monitor CPU temperature constantly.  CPUs don't heat up that fast.  It appears to be a data/device/reporting error.  [end part 1]

Comment: Where did you determine 88C is "running hot" and the max is 93C?  The max temp for an i7 CPU for that generation is 100C per [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193563/intel-core-i78665u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz.html).  The quantity of your data points isn't in question, but their relation to each other isn't clear.

Comment: 4.  A jump of 20C in 5 seconds, if continued at that rate would exceed the safe operating temperature within another 5 seconds.  If the fan *didn't* kick in it could be a catastrophic failure.   5.  I don't understand what you mean by "freezing of an image".  If you mean that why am I connecting kernel_task with my network going off-line, then it's because that's what everyone tells me--plus I'm monitoring the network, CPU, and process list.  When kernel_task takes 100% of the CPU, the network goes down.  At least I haven't had kernel_task take 500% of the CPU yet.

Comment: You cannot extrapolate a temperature increase in a linear fashion as you did.  For a CPU to that, you'd need a run away process.  Do you have evidence of this?  "Freezing image" was a bad term but "freezing out network activity causing Zoom disconnects" is speculation at best.  The CPU doesn't handle as much of the network stack as they once did.- that's offloaded onto the Broadcom chips now.  I think you're trying to "out think" and "out predict" these systems.  Start from a baseline - boot into Safe Mode to rule out 3rd party apps and kexts and see if your issues continue.

Comment: Over the past 3 months the CPU temperature has never exceeded 93C.  Usually as soon as the temperature gets to around 75C, the fan starts increasing.  Fan speed will always lag CPU temperature.   I don't really care about the CPU temperature or fan speed.  I care about the lying that kernel_task's job is to limit processes to bring the temperature down when it doesn't appear to do that.  I really would love kernel_task to stop halting network traffic.  You know it's really bad when giving a presentation in Zoom and the network drops for several minutes without warning and kernel_task did it.

Comment: As I stated previously, linking network latency to kernel_task is speculation at best because most handling of the network stack is offloaded.  This is probably where you want to focus your question - what's causing this network latency rather than assuming it's due to an issue with your CPU/temperature/kernel_task process.

Comment: I'm not running any 3rd party apps.  Either someone is lying about kernel_task dealing with CPU temperature or powermetrics is lying about the temperatures.  When kernel_task is at the top the CPU use, the network goes down.  When kernel_task releases the top spot on the CPU use, then the network comes back.  It's that simple.

Comment: When you say 100% CPU -- do you mean 100% of one core? `top` gives the same figure as Activity Monitor, which is per core. You've got 8 virtual cores, I think, so 100% is not so much.
You could certainly take it to an Apple Store to rule out any hardware problems. A diagnosis costs nothing.

Answer (score 3):

From the question and your comments, you seem to be very focused on someone (Apple?) "lying" about what `kernel_task` does. Nothing could be further from the truth. Actually, the source code is [freely available](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu).

The main problem with your arguments seem to be that you have come to the misunderstanding that `kernel_task`'s sole purpose is to regulate temperature. That is simply not true.

It is correct that `kernel_task` plays a role in throttling back a system when there is insufficient cooling. However, that is just a minor part of its operations.

In reality, `kernel_task` is not an ordinary program running. In this way it is different from all the other processes that you find running on your system. `kernel_task` instead is a placeholder for operations the operating system kernel performs.

The operating system kernel does some things autonomously, such as playing a part in regulating temperature, but the majority of kernel operations are actually the user space programs (your apps!) that ask it to perform some operation.

And here lies the main reason, why you're stuck solving the main issue. You seem to have the idea that the causality is that `kernel_task` does something on its own, consumes 100% CPU time, and this then makes your network fall out - so you must stop `kernel_task` from "doing this thing".

Rather it is most probably the other way around. I.e. your user space programs do "something" or your hardware circumstances are such that network processing can't continue, and as a consequence the kernel ends up "stuck" in a busy loop for longer periods of time.

My advice to you would be to temporarily drop the theory that `kernel_task` is the culprit and that "temperature" is the cause - and examine other possibilities:

The cause could be in your hardware. Try disconnecting all peripheral devices and try to see if that fixes the issue. If you have access to a similar computer, try duplicating your current software to that Mac and check if that also fails.

The cause could be in your configuration and/or data. Try creating a new user account and log in only with that to see if the problems goes away.

The cause could be in your software (bugs). Try booting in Recovery mode to start up a different version of everything, and see if the problem goes away. You can try upgrading to 12.6.8 or even Ventura to see if that is a fix.

Comment: I've already stated that it is clear that temperature is not the cause of `kernel_task` consuming a CPU since this happens when CPU temperatures are very average.  Unfortunately the problem happens only after the SMC has been reset 2+ weeks previous.  I'm not going to run without displays, an external keyboard and mouse for 2 weeks to see if the problem goes away.  I'm fully aware that CPU temperature is not the only thing `kernel_task` regulates or does.  I will eventually upgrade to Ventura once I get IT department approval and have time to deal with it.  This appears to be non-fixable.

Comment: If it only happens after the SMC has been reset 2 weeks prior - then please stop resetting the SMC. Generally, resetting the SMC is mostly a "placebo drug" that many seem to recommend with no reasonable argument for why that would be involved. You do no need need to run without displays and keyboard and mouse for 2 weeks - just keep these plugged in, and try without the rest of the peripherals if any. From your comment here, is it correct that you're only experiencing the problem for 30 seconds to a minute once every 2 weeks?

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to use the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client?

You have the **exact** same symptoms as I have had for months.

And the `kernel_task` is not the culprit, it's merely a symptom.

The issue, as far as I can understand, is the network filtering that the Cisco AnyConnect client installs. These can be faulty and either hog the system so the kernel struggles or run in the kernel and somehow slow it down.

Either way, I disabled the filters, well I actually removed them, but you can disable them too; go to **System Settings** > **Network** > **Filters** and either disable or remove them.

Here are some links that led me to this conclusion:

- [M1 MacBook Pro 2021 12.0.1 loses internet using Cisco Anyconnect 4.9.05042 resolves on reset](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253597438)
- [macOS Monterey and WiFi](https://community.cisco.com/t5/vpn/macos-monterey-and-wifi/td-p/4508944)
- [macOS 11: CPU hogged and DNS failing with link-local resolver address](https://quickview.cloudapps.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCvy23333)

Update:

You also need to make sure this is not running:

```
com.cisco.anyconnect.macos.acsockext
```

Look at the links I provided here to figure out how to disable it. Honestly, I no longer remember, but it involved a few restarts, as it is loaded on boot.